# How to Install Unity 8 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, unity8

Follow this site : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-unity-8-desktop-progress-video

I can not install unity8-lxc.
After applying:

> sudo apt install unity8-lxc

Error occured:

> E: Unable to locate package unity8-lxc

How to solve it?

Comment: sudo apt install unity8-desktop-session-mir

Comment: unity8-desktop-session-mir is ok, but it's likely very limited, can not install apps from store. Is it the unity8-lxc is different? Is something promising?